# TDD Books for C++

Tags: c++, tdd

What material would you recommend for stubborn C++ developers who need to learn to develop using TDD. I would like a book which contains examples which are more than just testing simple functions but which deal with the testing of classes making use of dependency injection.

Comment: Psst: Apparently book recomendation requests are against the rules (dunno, cant remember reading that bit) If so, expect downvotes &/or the question to be closed

Comment: [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052) has a section on TDD but more-so will simply encourage C++ developers to care more about their code, and to not feel overwhelmed.

Comment: gotta say this whole no books thing continually annoys

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I'd just go with a standard book on TDD - the basic principles are the important part, and the specific technologies used to express them are mere details.

I've had a lot of success with transplanting the basic principles in [Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) - which targets Java + JUnit + JMock + WindowLicker, and contains a running example which, while slighty toy-ish, still encompasses all the topics mentioned in your post - into C++ + Google Test + Google Mock + QTestLib.  The main stumbling block stems from the fact that the Java tools are in many ways more sophisticated than their C++ counterparts, but you can usually find some way to emulate the important parts in C++.